# UIAutomation iOS(test cases in Javascript UIAutomation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, automated-tests, instruments, ui-automation

I am working on UIAutomation. My question is can we take inputs from local json file in UIAutomation Script file. Means in UIAutomation Javascript can we execute data from other files. i want to give some inputs from other files in uiautomation java script file.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to have a data driven test for your UI.

[Appium](http://appium.io/getting-started.html) is an open source library that should allow you to write automated tests in whatever language you want. If you want to take input from a local file, write your test to read the inputs from that file.